# How can I use JOIN in the INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT :val
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.id = :id limit 1;
```

This query checks if `t2.id = :id` is true, then inserts. Now I also want to check `table3.id = :id` too. I think I have to use `JOIN` in this case. How can I do that?

I pass parameters like this:

```
$stm->bindValue(":val", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

---

**Note:** I know I can do that by a FK. but I don't want that.

Comment: Your `:val` will always be same value-string, not *safe column name* so it's same as `SELECT "some_string" FROM table2 t2`

Comment: @Justinas I don't understand .. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that PDO will escape your column name as simple string and as result you receive column name instead of column value.

Comment: If you print that SQL statement it would look something like this 'INSERT INTO table1 (col1) SELECT "fieldname" FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = 1 limit 1'.  You need to change the statement '$sql = INSERT INTO table1 (col1) SELECT ' . $value . ' FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = :id limit 1'

Comment: @Justinas Do you mean I have to use a `?` instead of ":val" because PDO interprets `:val` literally as a string ?

Comment: @stack No, I mean that params bindings are only for actual params and not for column/table names

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT :val
FROM table2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE t2.id = :id and t3.id = :id limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table_name object
INNER JOIN table_2 object2 ON object2.attribute = object2.attribute
(object2.attribute1, object2.attribute2, object.attribute1, object.attribute2) 
values
('somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue')
```